# Solving ODES in order to find unknown constants

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, chemistry

I am trying to solve a set of ODES which represent a second order consecutive chemical reaction.

```
eqn = {
   CA'[t] == -k1*CA[t]*CF[t],
   CB'[t] == k1*CA[t]*CF[t] - k2*CB[t]*CF[t],
   CC'[t] == k2*CB[t]*CF[t] - k3*CC[t]*CF[t],
   CD'[t] == k3*CC[t]*CF[t] - k4*CD[t]*CF[t],
   CE'[t] == k4*CD[t]*CF[t],
   CF'[t] == -(k1*CA[t]*CF[t] + k2*CB[t]*CF[t] + k3*CC[t]*CF[t] + 
       k4*CD[t]*CF[t])};
```

I want to solve these equations either for a generic expression for k1, k2, k3, or k4, or for a particular value with these particular boundary conditions, n.b. not to sure if both t= 1 and t = 4 needs to be used...

```
bcs = {
   CA[0] == 0.052952,
   CB[0] == 0,
   CC[0] == 0,
   CD[0] == 0,
   CE[0] == 0,
   CF[0] == 0.0226939,
   CA[1] == 0.047442,
   CB[1] == 4.08*10^-3,
   CC[1] == 1.24*10^-3,
   CD[1] == 0.19*10^-3,
   CE[1] == 0,
   CF[1] == 0.0191289,
   CA[4] == 0.043412,
   CB[4] == 5.03*10^-3,
   CC[4] == 3.54*10^-3,
   CD[4] == 0.90*10^-3,
   CE[4] == 0.07*10^-3,
   CF[4] == 0.0151489};
```

I have tried to use both NDsolve and Dsolve, NDSolve requires that I have initial values for k1, k2, k3, k4 and Dsolve doesn't seem to want to help... the rest of my code for DSolve...

```
vars = {CA[t], CB[t], CC[t], CD[t], CE[t], CF[t]};

solution[t_] = DSolve[{eqn, bcs}, vars, t]
```

Any help would be appreciated!! Chemistry is my forte not Mathematica!!

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I start with a simpler problem. eqn = {CA'[t] == -k1*CA[t]*CF[t], CB'[t] == k1 CA[t] CF[t] - k2 CB[t] CF[t], CF'[t] == -(k1*CA[t]*CF[t])}; vars = {CA[t], CB[t], CF[t]}; DSolve[eqn, vars, t] and that solves. Then I try adding initial conditions, one at a time, and find one or two that still solve, but much slower. Some parts of DSolve want exact rational coefficients. Other parts will convert decimal to rational, complain, but keep going. See if you can make any progress with this partial system.

Answer (score 2):

**This Answer has been revised in two respects**: First, boundary condition values are `Rationalize`d to postpone roundoff issues until the very end of the calculation.  Second, equations `ans3` are solved for `k1 τ1` instead of `Exp[-k1 τ1]`, etc.

Define

```
var = {CA[t], CB[t], CC[t], CD[t], CE[t], CF[t]};
bc0 = {CA[0] == 0.052952, CB[0] == 0, CC[0] == 0, 
  CD[0] == 0, CE[0] == 0, CF[0] == 0.0226939}/. z_Real :> Rationalize[z, 0];
bc1 = {CA[1] == 0.047442, CB[1] == 4.08*10^-3, CC[1] == 1.24*10^-3, 
  CD[1] == 0.19*10^-3, CE[1] == 0, CF[1] == 0.0191289}/. z_Real :> Rationalize[z, 0];
```

and `eqn` as in the Question.

These equations become linear, if `CF[t]` can be eliminated from the right side.  This is accomplished by the change of independent variable `t` to `τ` such that `D[τ[t] ,t] == CF[t]`.  The equations then become

```
eqn /. CF[t] -> 1 /. t -> τ;
```

which are solved by

```
ans1 = First@DSolve[{eqn /. CF[t] -> 1, bc0} /. t -> τ, var /. t -> τ, τ]
(* {CA[τ] -> 6619/(125000*E^(k1*τ)), CB[τ] -> 
  (-6619*E^(-(k1*τ) - k2*τ)*(-E^(k1*τ) + E^(k2*τ))*k1)/(125000*(k1 - k2)), ...} *)
```

To apply `bc1`, first isolate the four exponentials

```
ans2 = Collect[Expand[ans1], {Exp[-k1 τ], Exp[-k2 τ], Exp[-k3 τ], Exp[-k4 τ]},
  Simplify] /. Rule -> Equal;
```

and evaluate `ans2` at `τ1`, corresponding to `t = 1`.

```
ans3 = Simplify[ans2 /. τ -> τ1 /. (bc1 /. Equal -> Rule /. (1 -> τ1)) 
         /. {k1 -> k1/τ1, k2 -> k2/τ1, k3 -> k3/τ1, k4 -> k4/τ1}]
(* {26476/E^k1 == 23721, 
     ((510 + 6619/E^k1 - 6619/E^k2)*k1 - 510*k2)/(k1 - k2) == 0, ...} *)
```

Note the substitution `{k1 -> k1/τ1, k2 -> k2/τ1, k3 -> k3/τ1, k4 -> k4/τ1}`, which has the effect of eliminating the unknown quantity, `τ1`, from `ans3`.
The first four equations now can be solved for the four `k`. Because `NSolve` can handle only the first two transcendental equations, we proceed as follows.

```
a1 = First@NSolve[ans3[[1]], k1, Reals]
(* {k1 -> 0.109878} *)
a2 = First@NSolve[ans3[[2]] /. a1, k2]
(* {k2 -> 0.621713} *)
a3 = FindRoot[ans3[[3]] /. a1 /. a2, {k3, .4}]
(* {k3 -> 0.417505} *)
a4 = FindRoot[ans3[[4]] /. a1 /. a2 /. a3, {k4, 0}]
(* {k4 -> 2.28314*10^-15} *)
```

(Probably `k4` should be zero, but this is the best that `FindRoot` can do here.)  Inserting these `k` values into `ans3[5]` leaves a residual of order `10^-17`, essentially zero.  Why this should be expected is explained later.  On the other hand, inserting these `k` values into `ans3[6]` leaves a residual of `0.003565`.  Thus, the system of equations defined in the Question has no solution.

Minor modifications to the boundary conditions can, of course, make the system consistent.  For instance, subtracting `0.003565` from `bc1[6]` does so.

Finally, we remark that summing the first five `eqn` and their corresponding boundary conditions yields

```
{Simplify[Total[Cases[Take[eqn, 5], (z_ == _) -> z, {0, Infinity}]]] ==
   Simplify[Total[Cases[Take[eqn, 5], (_ == z_) -> z, {0, Infinity}]]], 
   Total[Cases[Take[bc0, 5], (_ == z_) -> z, {0, Infinity}]], 
   Total[Cases[Take[bc1, 5], (_ == z_) -> z, {0, Infinity}]]}
(* {Derivative[1][CA][t] + Derivative[1][CB][t] + Derivative[1][CC][t] + 
    Derivative[1][CD][t] + Derivative[1][CE][t] == 0, 6619/125000, 6619/125000}
```

Hence,

```
CA[t]  + CB[t]  + CC[t] + CD[t] + CE[t] == 6619/125000
```

which indicates that one of the first five `eqn` is redundant and could have been deleted.  In fact, `CE` is the logical variable to drop.

**Numerical Solution**

Once the ratios of the `K` are known, it is straightforward to integrate the original `eqn` and from there determine `τ1 = 52.3361`.  Rescaling the `k` by `τ1` then gives

[image]

Solutions at `t = 1` differ from `bc1` by of order 10^-9, except for `CF[1]`, which differs by `0.003565`, as expected.