# FullSimplify Produces Result that Includes Hold

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, hold

**Bug fixed in 10.2.0**

---

In the course of developing a solution to Question [79183](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79183/solving-odes-in-order-to-find-unknown-constants/79198#79198), I solved the equation

```
g[k2_] := (-510 k2 + (25761/4 - 6619 E^-k2) Log[26476/23721])/
  (-k2 + Log[26476/23721])
ans = Solve[g[k2] == 0, k2, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]

(* 1/680 (17174 Log[2] - 8587 Log[3] + 8587 Log[6619] - 8587 Log[7907] + 
     680 ProductLog[-((10579732023355105126853211737189792087286301059526347 
    (23721/6619)^(427/680) (2 Log[2] - Log[3] + Log[6619] - Log[7907]))/
    (6094176174584836754563581701959401731388819751567360 2^(87/340)))]) *)
```

and attempted to simplify it by

```
FullSimplify[ans]
```

However, the result included `Hold`,

```
(* 8587/680 Log[26476/23721] + 
     ProductLog[-((10579732023355105126853211737189792087286301059526347 
     Log[Hold[(26476/23721)^((23721/6619)^(427/680)/2^(87/340))]])/
     6094176174584836754563581701959401731388819751567360) *)
```

and

```
ReleaseHold[%]
```

produced the error message,

```
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>
```

without eliminating the `Hold`.

Surely, this is not proper behavior.  I have tried many approaches to work around this issue, but only

```
Simplify[ans - ans[[1]] ans[[2, 5]]] + Simplify[ans[[1]] ans[[2, 5]]]
```

produced good results

```
(* 8587/680 Log[26476/23721] + 
     ProductLog[-((10579732023355105126853211737189792087286301059526347 
     (23721/6619)^(427/680) Log[26476/23721])/
     (6094176174584836754563581701959401731388819751567360 2^(87/340)))]
```

Less satisfactory are results from

```
FullSimplify[ans, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
```

with

```
cf[e_] := ByteCount[e] + 100 Count[e, _Log, Infinity] + 
  100 Count[e, _ArcTanh, Infinity]
```

or

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, _Log, Infinity]
```

My questions are, how can I eliminate or avoid `Hold` from `FullSimplify[ans]`
 and, if that is not possible, is there an easier way to simplify `ans` than splitting it and then applying `Simplify` to each half, as shown above?

Comment: Offending expression: `(26476/23721)^((23721/6619)^(427/680)/2^(87/340)) `. Will investigate.

Comment: Simpler example: `x^((5/3)^(23/28)/2^(1/14))`.  `Trace` show what appears to be an infinite loop in which the exponent by itself evaluates to one form while the full `x^...` evaluates to a form with the exponent in a different form.  As if it cannot decide which form is simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been fixed as of version 10.2.0.

```
g[k2_] := (-510 k2 + (25761/4 - 6619 E^-k2) Log[26476/23721])/(-k2 + 
    Log[26476/23721])
ans = Solve[g[k2] == 0, k2, Reals][[1, 1, 2]];
FullSimplify[ans]

(* 8587/680 Log[26476/23721] + 
 ProductLog[-((
   10579732023355105126853211737189792087286301059526347 (23721/
     6619)^(427/680) Log[26476/23721])/(
   6094176174584836754563581701959401731388819751567360 2^(87/340)))] *)
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for previous versions?

Comment: I am not aware of any workaround for the underlying cause (arithmetic recursion).

Comment: Okay; thank you.